# Execute JS in a View with partial.js and d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, d3.js

I am using d3.js to generate plots from a JSON data set in a view of Partial.js framework.

Here's the code of the view page:

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


    <div id="truckDistance">
        <!-- div with the plot -->
    </div>
    <!-- popup -->
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <p class="heading">Node ID:
            <span id="node_id">word</span>
        </p>
        <p class="heading">Distance</p>
        <p class="indent">
            <span id="distance">5</span>km</p>
        <p class="heading">License Plate</p>
        <p class="indent">
            <span id="lplate">5</span>
        </p>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var margin = {
                top: 25,
                right: 75,
                bottom: 85,
                left: 85
            },
                w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
                h = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            var padding = 10;

            var colors = [
                ["Local", "#377EB8"],
                ["Global", "#4DAF4A"]
            ];

            var dataset = [{
                    "node_id": "8",
                    "distance": 7889,
                    "lplate": "50-HX-90"
                }, {
                    "node_id": "16",
                    "distance": 2334,
                    "lplate": "50-HX-90"
                }, {
                    "node_id": "24",
                    "distance": 2231,
                    "lplate": "50-HX-90"
                }, {
                    "node_id": "32",
                    "distance": 200,
                    "lplate": "50-HX-90"
                }, {
                    "node_id": "66",
                    "distance": 5000,
                    "lplate": "50-HX-90"
                }, {
                    "node_id": "94",
                    "distance": 233,
                    "lplate": "50-HZ-90"
                }
            ];

            var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05); // Width of each bar
            // ternary operator to determine if global or local has a larger scale

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                    return d.distance;
                })])
                .range([h, 0]);

            /*X Axis label*/
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return dataset[d].node_id;
            })
                .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5);

            var commaFormat = d3.format(','); //currently not used

            //SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("#truckDistance")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            // Graph Bars
            var sets = svg.selectAll(".set")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "set")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
            }); //moving all the bars to their positions (added /2)


            sets.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "distance")
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand() / 2)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.distance);
            })
                .attr("x", xScale.rangeBand() / 4) //This will get bars closer to the y-axis
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d.distance);
            })
                .attr("fill", colors[0][1])
                .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                var xPosition = parseFloat(xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand());
                var yPosition = h / 2;
                //Update Tooltip Position & value
                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                    .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                    .select("#lplate")
                    .text(d.lplate);
                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .select("#distance")
                    .text(d.distance); /*Assuming we will be rounding the Km's to units.*/
                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .select("#node_id")
                    .style("color", colors[1][1])
                    .text(d.node_id);
                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
            })

            .on("mouseout", function() {
                //Remove the tooltip
                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
            });



            // Labels
            sets.append("text")
                .attr("class", "distance")
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand() / 2)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.distance);
            })
                .attr("dy", 10)
                .attr("dx", (xScale.rangeBand() / 2.5)) // changed this to match translation
            //  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-family", "'Ubuntu', sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "8px")
                .attr("fill", "white")

            .text(function(d) {
                return commaFormat(d.distance);
            });



            // xAxis
            svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
            .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-25)";
            });
            // yAxis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0 ,0)")
                .call(yAxis);
            // xAxis label
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + " ," + (h + margin.bottom - 5) + ")")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Vehicle");
            //yAxis label
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                .attr("x", 0 - (h / 2))
                .attr("dy", "1em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Distance (Km)");

            // Title
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", (w / 2))
                .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .style("text-decoration", "underline")
                .text("Distance by Vehicle");

        }
    </script>
```

When i launch the application and try to access the page with this view the javascript code is not executed using the d3 Javascript and therefore not plot appears. If i inspect the code, instead of having the rendered SVG's i have only the native javascript.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Nop just not parsing at all. Apparently was something to do with Partials.js and some weird behavirour that didn't allowed JS to be executed in views. Changed the whole code to Express.js and now everything is solved

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this locally, I think you're just missing the close peren for your jQuery ready statement:

`});
    </script>`

Comment: Apparently was something wrong with the partial.js. Made it in Express.js with Handlebars and it's working sublime.

Comment: Actually, I was able to get your code working by just adding the parenthesis right before the close script tag, as I'd mentioned in my last comment.